# Converting Binary Search Tree to Linked List error

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to convert a bst into a linked list, but am getting an error when trying to recall the list to print on the display.

Here is my code for the main functions,

```
ListNodePtr createListnode(int key) {
    ListNodePtr newList = (ListNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

    if (newList != NULL) {
            newList->key = key;
            newList->next = NULL;
            return newList;
    } else {
            return NULL;
    }
}

ListNodePtr insertNodeIntoList(ListNodePtr root, const ListNodePtr z) {
    if (root == NULL) {
            root = createListnode(z->key);
    } else {
            root->next = insertNodeIntoList(root->next, z);
    }
    return root;
}

void linkedListINIT(ListNodePtr list, TreeNodePtr root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
            linkedListINIT(list, root->left);
            ListNodePtr current = createListnode(root->key);
            list = insertNodeIntoList(list, current);
            linkedListINIT(list, root->right);
    }
    return;
}

ListNodePtr convertBSTtoLinkedList(TreeNodePtr root) {
    ListNodePtr list = NULL;

    linkedListINIT(list, root);

    return list;
}
```

Here is the initialization for the listNodePtr and the print function.

```
struct ListNode {
    int key;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

typedef struct ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

and

```
void printList(ListNodePtr head) {
    if (head != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", head->key);
            printList(head->next);
    }
    return;
}
```

The issue is, when i try to print the final list, there is no output even though the 'current' variable outputs properly if I check it with print statements. I'm not really sure where it goes wrong, the main function just calls convertBSTtoLinkedList and printList. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the function call `linkedListINIT (list, root)` the function `linkedListINIT()` cannot possibly modify the variable `list`. It doesn't matter what it does; it simply *cannot possibly modify the variables passed as arguments* because the C language is strictly pass-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

In the function call `linkedListINIT (list, root)` the function `linkedListINIT()` cannot possibly modify the variable `list`. It doesn't matter how it's defined; it simply *cannot possibly modify the variables passed as arguments* because the C language is strictly pass-by-value.

So without reading anything more than the definition of `convertBSTtoLinkedList()` I know that it always returns NULL.

Comment: So would you have to make the arguments pointers? I tried that and I keep getting a segmentation fault..

Answer (score 0):

Modify functions `insertNodeIntoList()` and `linkedListINIT()` as follows

```
ListNodePtr insertNodeIntoList(ListNodePtr root, int z) {
    if (root == NULL) {
            root = createListnode(z);
    } else {
            root->next = insertNodeIntoList(root->next, z);
    }
    return root;
}

void linkedListINIT(ListNodePtr list, TreeNodePtr root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
            linkedListINIT(list, root->left);
            list = insertNodeIntoList(list, root->key);
            linkedListINIT(list, root->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

Hope it worked for you!